# Problem with log rotation of roundcube log files

Tags: debian, roundcube, log-rotation

I'm struggling with the log rotation of roundcube log files on my debian 11 server. The amount of files is getting higher and higher, so I have to delete them periodically.
[image]

Here you can see, how the files look like. All those suspicious files have ".1" at the end. What can cause this?

I don't want to work around it and delete these files again and again. Any suggestions on how to fix that?

Log rotation config looks like this:

```
{GUI_ROOT_DIR}/data/logs/roundcube/*
{
   create 640 {USER} {GROUP}
   compress
   delaycompress
   missingok
   notifempty
   rotate 7
   daily
}
```